# Java factorial calculation with thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, factorial

I achieved to calculate factorial with two threads without the pool. I have two factorial classes which are named Factorial1, Factorial2 and extends Thread class.  Let's consider I want to calculate the value of !160000. In Factorial1's run() method I do the multiplication in a for loop from i=2 to i=80000 and in Factorial2's from i=80001 to 160000. After that, i return both values and multiply them in the main method. When I compare the execution time it's much better (which is 5000 milliseconds) than the non-thread calculation's time (15000 milliseconds) even with two threads.

Now I want to write clean and better code because I saw the efficiency of threads at factorial calculation but when I use a thread pool to calculate the factorial value, the parallel calculation always takes more time than the non-thread calculation (nearly 16000). My code pieces look like:

```
for(int i=2; i<= Calculate; i++)
{
    myPool.execute(new Multiplication(result, i));
}
```

run() method which is in Multiplication class:

```
public void run() 
{
        s1.Mltply(s2); // s1 and s2 are instances of my Number class
                       // their fields holds BigInteger values
}
```

Mltply() method which is in Number class:

```
public void Multiply(int number)
{
    area.lock(); // result is going wrong without lock
    Number temp = new Number(number);
    value = value.multiply(temp.value); // value is a BigInteger
    area.unlock();       
}
```

In my opinion this lock may kills the all advantage of the thread usage because it seems like all that threads do is multiplication but nothing else. But without it, i can't even calculate the true result. Let's say i want to calculate !10, so thread1 calculates the 10*9*8*7*6 and thread2 calculate the 5*4*3*2*1. Is that the way I'm looking for? Is it even possible with thread pool? Of course execution time must be less than the normal calculation...

I appreciate all your help and suggestion.

EDIT: - My own solution to the problem -

```
public class MyMultiplication implements Runnable 
{
    public static BigInteger subResult1;
    public static BigInteger subResult2;
    int thread1StopsAt;
    int thread2StopsAt;
    long threadId;
    static boolean idIsSet=false;

    public MyMultiplication(BigInteger n1, int n2)  // First Thread
    {
        MyMultiplication.subResult1 = n1;
        this.thread1StopsAt = n2/2;

        thread2StopsAt = n2;

    }
    public MyMultiplication(int n2,BigInteger n1)   // Second Thread
    {
        MyMultiplication.subResult2 = n1;
        this.thread2StopsAt = n2;

        thread1StopsAt = n2/2;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        if(idIsSet==false)
        {
            threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId(); 
            idIsSet=true;            
        }
        if(Thread.currentThread().getId() == threadId)
        {
            for(int i=2; i<=thread1StopsAt; i++)
            {
                subResult1 = subResult1.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=thread1StopsAt+1; i<= thread2StopsAt; i++)
            {
                subResult2 = subResult2.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
            }
        }            
    }   
}
public class JavaApplication3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        int calculate=160000;
        long start = System.nanoTime(); 
        BigInteger num = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        for (int i = 2; i <= calculate; i++) 
        {
          num = num.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        double time = (end-start)/1000000.0;
        System.out.println("Without threads: \t" + 
        String.format("%.2f",time) + " miliseconds");    
        System.out.println("without threads Result: " + num);

        BigInteger num1 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        BigInteger num2 = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        ExecutorService myPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        start = System.nanoTime();

            myPool.execute(new MyMultiplication(num1,calculate));  
            Thread.sleep(100);
            myPool.execute(new MyMultiplication(calculate,num2));

        myPool.shutdown();
        while(!myPool.isTerminated())   {}  // waiting threads to end
        end = System.nanoTime();
        time = (end-start)/1000000.0;
        System.out.println("With threads: \t" +String.format("%.2f",time) 
        + " miliseconds");    
        BigInteger result = 

        MyMultiplication.subResult1.
        multiply(MyMultiplication.subResult2);
        System.out.println("With threads Result: " + result);
        System.out.println(MyMultiplication.subResult1);
        System.out.println(MyMultiplication.subResult2);
    }   
}
```

input : !160000
Execution time without threads : 15000 milliseconds
Execution time with 2 threads  : 4500  milliseconds

Thanks for ideas and suggestions.

Comment: You have omitted too​ many details: [mcve]

Comment: What does this line do: `Number temp = new Number(number);` I can't see temp being used.

Comment: Unless you are calculating the factorial of a significantly large number, like 10,000, you are not going to see consistent improvements from multi-threading. The overhead of thread management will overwhelm any advantage of splitting up the calculation, and you can't micro-benchmark iteration counts of 10,000 due to JIT warmup time.  In short, you don't need or want multithreading for such a small problem.

Comment: @Jhonny007 I use temp at multiply() function

Comment: @JimGarrison i mentioned above that I calculated !160000 without threads (15000 milliseconds) and with two threads (5000 milliseconds). So I think that 160000 is much 'larger' than 10000 and 10 seconds for such a small procces is not a 'small' amount of time. I was wondering how can I achieve the same goal with the thread pool, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Threads have to run independent to run fast. Many dependencies like locks, synchronized parts of your code or some system calls leads to sleeping threads which are waiting to access some resources.

In your case you should minimize the time a thread is inside the lock. Maybe I am wrong, but it seems like you create a thread for each number. So for `1.000!` you spawn 1.000 Threads. All of them trying to get the lock on `area` and are not able to calculate anything, because one thread has become the lock and all other threads have to wait until the lock is unlocked again. So the threads are only running in serial which is as fast as your non-threaded example plus the extra time for locking and unlocking, thread management and so on. Oh, and because of cpu's context switching it gets even worse.

Your first attempt to splitt the factorial in two threads is the better one. Each thread can calculate its own result and only when they are done the threads have to communicate with each other. So they are independent most of the time.

Now you have to generalize this solution. To reduce context switching of the cpu you only want as many threads as your cpu has cores (maybe a little bit less because of your OS). Every thread gets a rang of numbers and calculates their product. After this it locks the overall result and adds its own result to it.

This should improve the performance of your problem.

---

Update: You ask for additional advice:

You said you have two classes `Factorial1` and `Factorial2`. Probably they have their ranges hard codes. You only need one class which takes the range as constructor arguments. This class implements Runnable so it has a `run`-Method which multiplies all values in that range.

In you `main`-method you can do something like that:

```
int n = 160_000;
int threads = 2;
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
    int start = i * (n/threads) + 1;
    int end = (i + 1) * (n/threads) + 1;
    executor.execute(new Factorial(start, end));
}
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Now you have calculated the result of each thread but not the overall result. This can be solved by a `BigInteger` which is visible to the `Factorial`-class (like a `static BigInteger reuslt;` in the same main class.) and a lock, too. In the `run`-method of `Factorial` you can calculate the overall result by locking the lock and calculation the result:

```
Main.lock.lock();
Main.result = Main.result.multiply(value);
Main.lock.unlock();
```

---

Some additional advice for the future: This isn't really clean because `Factorial` needs to have information about your main class, so it has a dependency to it. But `ExecutorService` returns a `Future<T>`-Object which can be used to receive the result of the thread. Using this `Future`-Object you don't need to use locks. But this needs some extra work, so just try to get this running for now ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. But  do you have an advice about how can i imitate my first and successful approach in thread pool?

Answer (score 1):

You may calculate `!160000` concurrently without using a lock by splitting `160000` into disjunct junks as you explaint by splitting it into 2..80000 and 80001..160000.

But you may achieve this by using the Java Stream API:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 160000).parallel()
    .mapToObj(val -> BigInteger.valueOf(val))
    .reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply);
```

It does exactly what you try to do. It splits the whole range into junks, establishes a thread pool and computes the partial results. Afterwards it joins the partial results into a single result.

So why do you bother doing it by yourself? Just practicing clean coding?

On my real 4 core machine computation in a for loop took 8 times longer than using a parallel stream.

Comment: I just wonder if i can get the same result and good execution time with thread pool. I'm new to thread pools but I suppose this can be done with it, just don't know how to. Creating two same factorial classes only with different for loops in run() method isn't clear code i think.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my *Java Stream API* solution here another solution which uses a self-managed thread-pool as you demanded:

```
public static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 10000;

public static BigInteger fac(int max) {
    ExecutorService executor = newCachedThreadPool();
    try {
        return rangeClosed(0, (max - 1) / CHUNK_SIZE)
                .mapToObj(val -> executor.submit(() -> prod(leftBound(val), rightBound(val, max))))
                .map(future -> valueOf(future))
                .reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply);
    } finally {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}

private static int leftBound(int chunkNo) {
    return chunkNo * CHUNK_SIZE + 1;
}

private static int rightBound(int chunkNo, int max) {
    return Math.min((chunkNo + 1) * CHUNK_SIZE, max);
}

private static BigInteger valueOf(Future<BigInteger> future) {
    try {
        return future.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static BigInteger prod(int min, int max) {
    BigInteger res = BigInteger.valueOf(min);
    for (int val = min + 1; val <= max; val++) {
        res = res.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(val));
    }
    return res;
}
```